# Comparing spelling of strings from db and csv file

Tags: python, sql-server

I'm mapping a table from a CSV file, and comparing some values to keys in a DB in order to fetch another value.

There's a possibility of spelling mistakes when people write the CSV files, so sometimes some values are not found in the db.

E.g. person writes: 'Contributions Other', db has a key of 'ContributionsOther'

What I did was remove all the spaces and dashes and lowercased both the value from the CSV and converted the values when creating a table from the db. Here are the following methods:

```
def get_trade_type_mappings(self):
    sql = """
    SELECT Code, TradeTypeID
    FROM dbo.TradeType"""

    with self.job.connect(database='rap') as conn:
        trade_types = etl.fromdb(conn, sql)
        trade_types.convert('Code', lambda x: x.replace(' ', '').replace('-', '').lower())
        return dict(trade_types)

def fetch_trade_type_id(self, trade_type):
    # Prevents case and space difference causing issues
    trade_type = trade_type.replace(' ', '').replace('-', '').lower()
    if trade_type == 'cover':
        trade_type = 'covershort'
    elif trade_type == 'short':
        trade_type = 'sellshort'

    return self.get_trade_type_mappings.get(trade_type)
```

I'm trying to think of any other possible occurrences that might be prone to error.

What I wrote will work for stuff like:
'Contribution Other' vs. 'ContributionOther'
but not for:
'ContributionOthers' vs. 'ContributionOther'

Anything else you think would be useful? I've seen a Levenshtein Distance method for spelling comparison between two words... maybe I could integrate that.

Comment: What are you expecting as an answer here?

Comment: Ideas to solve possible edge cases like the one I listed at the bottom.

Comment: That is way too broad for this site. There are **SO** many possible edge cases. What about Contribution-Otherx? Or any of a zillion other close probabilities. And what happens when you extend the list of likely fat fingered results to cover the edge cases that you create two possible paths? Levenshtein, SOUNDEX are both possible helpers but nothing is going to be foolproof because you are trying to make string that are pretty close be treated as equal.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks anyway.